# lambda equivalent to collection.Count(predicate)

Tags: c#, linq

What would be a LINQ query-syntax equivalent for the following code

```
int[] numbers = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int count = numbers.Count(x => x > 5 == true);
```

I tried this one, but it didn't compile:

```
var c = from number in numbers where number > 5 select numbers.Count;
```

this one didn't compile either:

```
var c = from number in numbers where number > 5 select new {numbers.Count};
```

Comment: `numbers.Count(x => x > 5)` ? Anyway, there is no equivalent to `Count` in query syntax. You have to wrap your query into brackets and call then `Count` with or without predicate.

Comment: @Mitten It seems you may have your semantics a bit off.  You already have the lambda expression - the lambda operator is `=>`, so any expression with this operator is a lambda expression.  What you're asking for here is to convert your lambda expression into an equivalent expression that uses SQL-like-syntax-operators.

Comment: @Gjeltema I see - I may have the terminology off ... is there a short name for "SQL-like-syntax-operators"? Thank you.

Comment: @Mitten "Query syntax" seems to be the most commonly used (see Ilya's comment above mine).

Comment: Thank you @Gjeltema. Would upvote your comment as soon as I get more reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close, just need to wrap the LINQ expression in parenthesis like this:

```
var c = (from number in numbers where number > 5 select number).Count();
```

Comment: I think you meant `select number`, although what you have will compile and will give the right result.

Comment: @hvd BTW why does both .. select number).Count() and .. select numbers.Count() would produce the same result (3) ? I would have thought a collection (numbers) need to be selected so it could be queried for a size, as a single number don't have a size property.

Comment: @Mitten - It works because you're not actually using the selected value, just counting the number of results. You could put anything in place of `numbers` and it would have the same result e.g. `(from number in numbers where number > 5 select 1).Count();`

Answer (score 3):

The LINQ style with `from` and `in` is called "query syntax":

```
from row in table where row.col1 < 10 select row.col1
```

It usually contains fewer lambda expressions than "method syntax":

```
table.rows.Where(r => r.col1 < 10).Select(r => r.col1)
```

You can mix them up too.  For example, this creates a single group for all rows, and computes the row count.  A method call like `FirstOrDefault()` is required to materialize the value:

```
int c = (
        from n in numbers 
        where n > 5 
        group n by 1 into g 
        select g.Count()
        ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is query syntax, and not all LINQ methods have an equivalent in query syntax. The most concise expression is `numbers.Count(x => x > 5)`. From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx):

> Some query operations, such as `Count` or `Max`, have no equivalent query expression clause and must therefore be expressed as a method call. Method syntax can be combined with query syntax in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numbers = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var n = numbers.Where(x => x > 5).Count();
```

Answer (score -1):

int[] numbers = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var count = numbers.Count(x => x > 5);

Comment: This only repeats the code in the question (since `== true` is redundant). The accepted answer is the only necessary answer here.